# Angular 5 get text of select option in formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting value for select option and I want to get the selected option text in the form I have used ReactiveFrom

```
[
  {
    "brokerId": 10,
    "brokerName": "Kennedy, Shea Peter"
  },
  {
    "brokerId": 51,
    "brokerName": "Fernandez, Jaime"
  },
  {
    "brokerId": 279,
    "brokerName": "Stapleton, Bill "
  },
  {
    "brokerId": 489,
    "brokerName": "Marlow, Jeff  D."
  },
]
```

Component HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="SplitBrokerForm">
        <select formControlName="splitbrokerid1">
            <option>-choose-</option>
            <option *ngFor="let b of broker" value="{{b.brokerId}}" [selected]="b.brokerId == splitbrokerid1">{{b.brokerName}}</option>
        </select>   
</form>
```

is there any way to get it.?

Comment: You mean `{{b.brokerName}}` ?

Comment: Yes i want to get brokername

Comment: so your broker object/array has brokerName ?

Comment: yes i updated my question

Comment: whats the issue here check this I have made stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ytfqe?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the value as a property binding i have added a working example here check this out 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-example?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: want both "brokerId and brokerName"

Comment: You needn't use [selected]="....", ¡it's a select!. About your question, your option value can be the all object <option [ngValue]="b">{{b.brokerName}}</option>